# How to Secure php picture upload system

Tags: php, security, upload, system, image

I want to make picture upload system with php and i want users will be able to upload just 
png,jpg files and not viruses or other files. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

step 1: Check the extension (extension file ends with)

step 2: Check the MIME type ($file_info = getimagesize($_FILES['image_file']; $file_mime = $file_info['mime'];)

only allow the those image extension which you want to upload , for that you can make the white list

try something like

```
$whitelist = array(".jpeg",".jpg",".png");
foreach ($whitelist as $item)
    {


       if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']))
               {
                   $uploaddir='uploads/uploads_image/';
                   $uploadfilename=mysql_prep(basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']));
                    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
                   $iv=  mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
                   $newname= mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "this is the key",$uploadfilename.time(), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
                   $newfilename=  (bin2hex($newname));
                   $uploadfile=$uploaddir.$newfilename.".png";
                   $access=true;
               }
    }
```

you can also block the ip of the user if user try to upload miscellaneous file by making the black list

```
foreach ($blacklist as $item) 
    {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) 
            {
                $network = ip2long("10.12.0.0");
                $mask = ip2long("255.255.0.0");
                $ip = ip2long($_SERVER{'REMOTE_HOST'});
                if (($network & $mask) == ($ip & $mask)) {
                  die("Unauthorized");
                }
            }


    }
```

Comment: can u give me some popular code for this,like something that everyone use it for that?

Comment: @BlackshadowBlackshadow  you can try http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2181-PHP-Process-files-and-images-uploaded-via-a-form.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
```

for more information about this [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: can u give me some popular code for this,like something that everyone use it for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
1st check:-
//check if contain php and kill it 
 $pos = strpos($filename,'php');
 if(!($pos === false)) {
  die('error');
 }

2nd check:-
//get the file ext
 $file_ext = strrchr($filename, '.');
$image_list = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png"); 
 if (!(in_array($file_ext, $image_list))) {
        die('not allowed extension,please upload images only');
 }


3rd check:-    
$fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type==image/jpeg || image/gif || image/png"];

4th check:-     
preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName);

hope these checks solve your problem....
```